# multi-computer makePSOCKcluster on Windows: Building a step-by-step guide

Tags: r, ssh, parallel-processing, putty

I've been trying to build a cluster using multiple computers for three days now and have failed spectacularly.  So now I'm going to try to suck a bunch of you into solving my problem for me.  If all goes well, I would hope we can generate a step-by-step guide to use as a reference to do this in the future, because as of yet, I haven't managed to find a decent reference for setting this up (perhaps it's too specific a task?)

In my case, let's assume Windows 7, with PuTTY as the SSH client, and 'localhost' is going to serve as the master.

Furthermore, let's assume only two computers on the same network for now.  I imagine the process will generalize easily enough that if I can get it to work on two computers, I can get it to work on three.  So we'll work on `localhost` and `remote-computer`.

Here's what I've gathered so far (with references linked at the bottom)

1. Install PuTTY on `localhost`.
2. Install PuTTY on `remote-computer`
3. Install an SSH server on `remote-computer`
4. Assign it a port to listen on? (I'm not sure about this step)
5. Install R on `localhost`
6. Install the same version of R on `remote-computer`
7. Add R to the PATH environment variable on both `localhost` and `remote-computer`
8. Run the R code below from `localhost`

code:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(c(rep("localhost", 2),
                         rep("remote-computer", 2)))
```

So far, I've done steps 1-3, not sure if I need to do 4, done 5-7, and the code for step 8 just hangs indefinitely.

When I check my SSH server logs, it doesn't appear that I'm hitting the SSH server from `localhost`.  So it appears that my first problem is configuring the SSH correctly.  Has anyone succeeded in doing this and would you be willing to share your expertise?

EDIT
Oops: references
http://www.milanor.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/03.FirstStepinParallelComputing.pdf

[R Parallel - connecting to remote cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508400/r-parallel-connecting-to-remote-cores)

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2010-October/000780.html

Comment: Note that makePSOCKcluster doesn't use ssh to start the workers on localhost, so you wouldn't expect to see anything in the SSH server logs of your local machine.

Comment: I would expect to see something on the remote machine, however.  And I wasn't seeing anything at the time I wrote this question.  I'll post an update before I leave work today.  I think I've gotten closer.

Answer (score 4):

At best, this is a partial answer.  I'm still not establishing a cluster, but the steps described here are a pretty good record of how I've gotten to this point.

### CONFIGURATIONS:

1. Install PuTTY on 'remote-computer'
2. Install SSH server on 'remote-computer'
3. Install R on 'remote-computer' (Use the same version of R as on 'localhost')
4. Add R to the PATH
5. Install PuTTY on 'localhost'
6. Install R on 'localhost'
7. Add R to the PATH

### TESTING THE CONNECTION: PHASE I

1. From the command line, run

`C:\PuTTYPath\plink.exe -pw [password] [username]@[remote_ip_address] Rscript -e rnorm(100)`

(Confirm return of 100 normal random variates

2. From the command line, run

`C:\PuTTYPath\plink.exe -pw [password] [username]@[remoate_ip_address] RScript -e parallel:::.slaveRSOCK() MASTER=[local_ip_address] PORT=100501 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE`

(Confirm that a session is started on the SSH server logs on 'remote-computer')

### TESTING THE CONNECTION: PHASE II

1. From an R Session, run

   `system(paste0("C:/PuTTYPath/plink.exe -pw [password] ",
                 "[username]@[remote_ip_address] ", 
                 "RScript -e rnorm(100)"))`

   (Confirm return of 100 normal random variates)
2. From an R session, run

   `system(paste0("C:/PuTTY/plink.exe ",
                "-pw [password] ",
                "[username]@[remote_ip_address] ", 
                "RScript -e parallel:::.slaveRSOCK() ",
                "MASTER=[local_ip_address] ",
                "PORT=100501 ",
                "OUT=/dev/null ", 
                "TIMEOUT=2592000 ",
                "METHODS=TRUE ", 
                "XDR=TRUE"))`

(Confirm that a session is started and maintained on the SSH server logs on 'remote-computer'

### ESTABLISH A CLUSTER

1. From an R Session, run

   `library(snow)`
   `cl <- makeCluster(spec = c("localhost", "[remote_ip_address]"),
                 rshcmd = "C:/PuTTY/plink.exe -pw [password]",
                 host = "[local_ip_address]")`

(A session should be started and maintained on the SSH server logs on 'remote-computer'.
 Ideally, the function will complete at 'cl' be assigned)

Establishing the cluster is the point at which I'm failing.  I run `makeCluster` and watch my SSH server logs.  It shows a connection is made and then immediately closed. `makeCluster` never finishes running, `cl` is not assigned, and I'm stuck on how to go on.  I'm not even sure if this is an R problem or a configuration problem at this point.

### EDIT AND RESOLUTION:

For no good reason, I tried running this with the `snow` package, as shown in the "Establish a Cluster" section above.  When I used the `snow` package, the cluster is built and runs stably.  Not sure why I couldn't get this to work with the `parallel` package, but at least I've got something functional.

Comment: By default, R needs to be installed with the same path on all machines because by default makeCluster uses the full path to Rscript on the master machine when starting the workers. If it isn't installed in the same place, you could try using the makeCluster `homogeneous=FALSE` option which will cause it to use simply "Rscript", as you are doing in your tests. If you don't set `homogeneous=FALSE`, I don't think R needs to be in PATH on the remote machines.

Comment: I made sure to do the installation of R in such a manner that they are identical.  I found I still needed to add R to the PATH, however, because when I run `makeCluster` on R3.2.2, it insists on using the path for R3.1.1 (and I checked, R3.2.2 is on my PATH).  Adding R to the PATHs on both computers let me just specify `rscript = "RScript"`.  But, by careful design, the machines are homogenous.  Using `homogenous = TRUE` and `homogenous = FALSE` don't change the current results.  I'm still seeing my local machine connect to the remote and then immediately terminate the connection.

Comment: Just added an edit--I managed to get the cluster to work by using the `snow` package instead of the `parallel` package.  I'm not sure I'm educated enough to know why it works in `snow` and not in `parallel`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for establishing clusters across several computers in Windows, @Benjamin's answer is almost correct, you need to follow his instructions until the last step, which is ESTABLISH A CLUSTER, and make sure the previous steps are all working in your computer. My solution is based on the package 'Parallel' instead of 'snow', which are essentially same.

### Solution

Code template:

```
machineAddresses <-list(list(host='[Server address]',user='[user name]',rscript="[The Rscript file in the server]",rshcmd="plink -pw [Your password]"))
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(machineAddresses,manual = F)
```

You have to fill all the [] in your code. In my computer, it is:

```
machineAddresses <-list(list(host='192.168.1.220',user='jeff',rscript="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/bin/Rscript",rshcmd="plink -pw qwer"))
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(machineAddresses,manual = F)
```

### Reason

Running cluster in Windows is very tricky, the function makePSOCKcluster usually does not work as expected. The easiest way to make it work is to change manual=F to manual=T and manually create workers. Here is a related post, which talks about why the function makePSOCKcluster will hang forever, and I think these two post basically stuck in the same place. I also post my answer to that question to discuss how to make it work.

[R Parallel - connecting to remote cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508400/r-parallel-connecting-to-remote-cores)

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have the reputation to post a comment on Jeff's answer, I will post this as an answer:

The reason I have found that automatic start of cluster nodes using makePSOCKcluster does not work in Windows is that the `arg` and the `outfile` arguments in the internal `parallel` function `newPSOCKnode` are wrapped in the `shQuotes` function. This causes the combination of cmd.exe and Rscript.exe to return an error, which leads to `makePSOCKcluster` hanging forever.

The following two function definitions enable the automatic starting of the cluster nodes using `makePSOCKcluter`, assuming a proper configuration of `ssh` or `putty`/`plink` for key-based password-less login:

```
makePSOCKcluster <- function (names, ...) 
{
  if (is.numeric(names)) {
    names <- as.integer(names[1L])
    if (is.na(names) || names < 1L) 
      stop("numeric 'names' must be >= 1")
    names <- rep("localhost", names)
  }
  parallel:::.check_ncores(length(names))
  options <- parallel:::addClusterOptions(parallel:::defaultClusterOptions, list(...))
  cl <- vector("list", length(names))
  for (i in seq_along(cl)) cl[[i]] <- newPSOCKnode(names[[i]], 
                                                   options = options, rank = i)
  class(cl) <- c("SOCKcluster", "cluster")
  cl
}

newPSOCKnode <- function (machine = "localhost", ..., options = parallel:::defaultClusterOptions, 
                          rank) 
{
  options <- parallel:::addClusterOptions(options, list(...))
  if (is.list(machine)) {
    options <- parallel:::addClusterOptions(options, machine)
    machine <- machine$host
  }
  outfile <- parallel:::getClusterOption("outfile", options)
  master <- if (machine == "localhost") 
    "localhost"
  else parallel:::getClusterOption("master", options)
  port <- parallel:::getClusterOption("port", options)
  setup_timeout <- parallel:::getClusterOption("setup_timeout", options)
  manual <- parallel:::getClusterOption("manual", options)
  timeout <- parallel:::getClusterOption("timeout", options)
  methods <- parallel:::getClusterOption("methods", options)
  useXDR <- parallel:::getClusterOption("useXDR", options)
  env <- paste0("MASTER=", master, " PORT=", port, " OUT=", 
                #shQuote(outfile), " SETUPTIMEOUT=", setup_timeout, " TIMEOUT=", 
                (outfile), " SETUPTIMEOUT=", setup_timeout, " TIMEOUT=", 
                timeout, " XDR=", useXDR)
  arg <- "parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()"
  rscript <- if (parallel:::getClusterOption("homogeneous", options)) {
    shQuote(parallel:::getClusterOption("rscript", options))
  }
  else "Rscript"
  rscript_args <- parallel:::getClusterOption("rscript_args", options)
  if (methods) 
    rscript_args <- c("--default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods", 
                      rscript_args)
  cmd <- if (length(rscript_args)) 
    paste(rscript, paste(rscript_args, collapse = " "), "-e", 
          #shQuote(arg), env)
          arg, env)
  #else paste(rscript, "-e", shQuote(arg), env)
  else paste(rscript, "-e", arg, env)
  renice <- parallel:::getClusterOption("renice", options)
  if (!is.na(renice) && renice) 
    cmd <- sprintf("nice +%d %s", as.integer(renice), cmd)
  if (manual) {
    cat("Manually start worker on", machine, "with\n    ", 
        cmd, "\n")
    utils::flush.console()
  }
  else {
    if (machine != "localhost") {
      rshcmd <- parallel:::getClusterOption("rshcmd", options)
      user <- parallel:::getClusterOption("user", options)
      cmd <- shQuote(cmd)
      cmd <- paste(rshcmd, "-l", user, machine, cmd)
    }
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
      system(cmd, wait = FALSE, input = "")
    }
    else system(cmd, wait = FALSE)
  }
  con <- socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, 
                          blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b", timeout = timeout)
  structure(list(con = con, host = machine, rank = rank), class = if (useXDR) 
    "SOCKnode"
    else "SOCK0node")
}
```

I plan to update this response with more complete setup instructions when I have the chance.